# How run a statement on change as well as on load event in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable a button; on page load as well as on checkbox change

Following is JQuery:

```
var myquery= {

init: function () {
     $('#buttonName').prop('disabled', !$("input[name='checkboxName'").is(':checked')); 
     // Run on page load

    $("input[name='checkboxName'").change(function() {
        $('#buttonName').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))
    }); // Run on event
  }
};
$(document).ready(myquery.init());
```

How can i handle onLoad as well as change events together without changing inside init only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is how you are adding the dom ready handler, you are invoking the `init` method before the dom ready and is passing the value returned by it(`undefined`) as the dom ready handler

Also you can trigger the change handler on page load, to update the status

```
var myquery = {

    init: function () {
        $("input[name='checkboxName'").change(function () {
            $('#buttonName').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))
        }).change();
    }
};
$(document).ready(myquery.init);
```

Comment: And `trigger('change')` can also be used

Comment: but i want to execute onLoad as well as onChange like on change  or on load of checkbox do this and do that. will above statement work. Let me try

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm saying `.trigger('change')` can also be used as optional to `.change()`.

Comment: @fatherazrael what do you mean by onload of checkboxes... whether they are created after the page is loaded